# Question about omitting the return statement in a function declaration

Tags: c

Consider the following code for producing a list of numbers from 0 to 9 along with values of 2 and -3 raised to the power of the corresponding number from the list:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int power(int m, int n);

main()
{
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i <= 10; ++i)
      printf("%d %d %d\n", i, power(2, i), power(-3, i));
   return 0;
}

int power(int base, int n)
{
   int i, p;

   p = 1;
   for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
      p = p * base;
   // return statement purposefully omitted. //
}
```

Of course the program does not work properly without the return statement for the power function, however by running the written code I get the following output:

```
0 1 1
1 2 2
2 3 3
3 4 4
4 5 5
5 6 6
6 7 7
7 8 8
8 9 9
9 10 10
```

And I'm wondering where are the numbers in the second and third column of the output coming from? In lack of a valid return value of power, the control transfers back to the calling function, but why does it output these numbers?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: missing ';' in for loop in power().

Comment: Try to put some `printf("");` or similar at the end of your `power` function. I guess your output will change significantly.

Comment: Technically that has undefined behaviour and is meaningless to reason about, but in practice those numbers just happened to be in the place where the returned value should have been.

Comment: It likely means that your code stores `p` at `EAX` register. Since the returned value is stored there, your function accidentally returns what you want.

Comment: If you don't return any value. It just becomes any random value like it *never existed*... And that phenomenon is a part of the term *undefined behavior*...

Comment: Looking at this code, you have much bigger problems that you should focus on, rather than the pointless task of analysing the result of undefined behavior. Specifically, you need to figure out why you are writing C according to a 30 years old, 20 years obsolete standard in the year 2019.

Comment: Aside: it does not matter to the compiler that the function declaration `int power(int m, int n);` is different to its implementation but it would make it clearer to people reading the code which way round its arguments are, as in `int power(int base, int n)`.

Comment: To expand on what `Lundin` was saying, you shouldn't need to pre-declare your variables (e.g., `int i, p` at the top of the function instead of declaring them when they're used), and you should put the type for every function and variable even if it's `int` (as in `int main()`, not `main()`).

Comment: @Ruks not a random value, rather an undetermined value.

Comment: @dyukha The function doesn't return what was wanted; `p` should be 1, 2, 4, 8, ... for the second column and 1, -3, 9, -27, ... for the third column. I'd say it seems to store `i` in EAX, since what it returns is one more than `n`.

Comment: Google the term "undefined behaviour". And be aware that "undefined behaviour" includes "apparently working fine".

Comment: @DanielH, you are right. Time to go to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @dyukha and @Daniel H, the value returned is "whatever is in your `EAX` register". Your function finishes on a `for`-loop, hence the last instruction realized before returning (ending the function) probably was a branching test, to check if `i <= n` (your loop condition). You can actually check on what variable is set to your `EAX` register by using your compiler to generate the assembly version of your code (option `-S`). You may try to follow what values are set into your register before the call to

```
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

at the end of your function.

On my computer, I tried with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2), which generate the following for my function:

```
    movl    %edi, -8(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -12(%rbp)
    movl    $1, -20(%rbp)
    movl    $1, -16(%rbp)
LBB2_1:                                 ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    cmpl    -16(%rbp), %eax
    jl  LBB2_4
## BB#2:                                ##   in Loop: Header=BB2_1 Depth=1
    movl    -20(%rbp), %eax
    imull   -8(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, -20(%rbp)
## BB#3:                                ##   in Loop: Header=BB2_1 Depth=1
    movl    -16(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $1, %eax
    movl    %eax, -16(%rbp)
    jmp LBB2_1
LBB2_4:
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

As you can see, I have 4 remarkable addresses: `-8(%rbp)`, `-12(%rbp)`, `-16(%rbp)` and `-20(%rbp)`. Given the order of declaration in the C code, and the order of initialisation, `-8(%rbp)` is `base`, `-12(%rbp)` is `n`, `-16(%rbp)` is `i` and `-20(%rbp)` is `p`.

`LBB2_1` is your loop condition. The instructions for the check are
* move value of `n` in `%eax`
* is the value of `%eax` lower then the value of `i`, store the result in `%eax`
* if `%eax` says that it was lower, go to label `LBB2_4` else continue to next instruction

The three instructions after BB#2 are you actual multiplication. The three instructions after BB#3 are your increment of `i`, which is followed by an unconditional jump to your loop condition at label `LBB2_1`.

The ending of the power function is to take whatever is in memory address `-4(%rbp)`, tu put it in `%eax`, and then leave the function (reset stack pointer, put value in `%eax` to the proper variable in the previous stack frame).

In the code produced by my compiler, I don't see the same result as you do, as I get every time the last two columns equal to 0 (`-4(%rbp)` is never set to anything). Except when adding a call to another function `foo`, taking two integers as parameters, having two local integer variables (to ensure that my new stack frame will be the same size as the power function one). This function actually set the address `-4(%rbp)`. When calling my function right before entering the loop, I effectively find the value from `-4(%rbp)` as set in my function `foo` returned in my function `power`.

As a colleague just told me, playing with undefined behaviour is dangerous as your compiler is allowed to treat it any way it likes. It could be summoning a demon for what it's worth.

In definitive, or TL;DR, this undefined behaviour is handle in *some way* by the compiler. Whether some value is moved from one local variable, defined or not, or nothing special is moved to the register `%eax` is up to the compiler. Anyway, whatever was hanging in there, got returned when `retq` is called.